# How to set difftool/mergetool for a specific file extension in Git?

Tags: git, version-control, git-merge, git-diff, git-config

Is it possible to set a custom tool for merging files with a specific extension in Git?

Thanks for any pointers!

**Update**

I wasn't able to come up with any better solution than defining a custom difftool and calling it by hand as @jarodeells suggested:

```
[diff]
    tool = mydiff
[difftool "mydiff"]
    cmd="script.sh \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\""
```

Then calling it explicitly:

```
$ git difftool -t mydiff someFileWith.ext
```

Comment: Can you be please more specific about the solution? Also I think there is one extra quote at the end of cmd line.

Comment: Actually, there was an additional `"` after `script.sh` which wasn't necessary. Now it should be fine :-)

Comment: I did the solution you proposed but when I do `git difftool --cached` script does not catch the option and does not work. Have you encountered that problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If not already supported, install a shell script that keys off the extension and calls the correct merge tool.

Comment: Yeah, that could be a solution, but I'd like to avoid custom solutions. I'm interested if it is possible through `gitconfig` (as the tags indicate).

Answer (score 8):

*Update: See @Ackdari comments below. The external tool doesn't have to be command-line based. I'm not sure how git uses `binary = True` when an external tool is used, but I suspect it might be needed for all flows to work.*

<s>If your external diff tool* is command-line only (no GUI),</s> You can use the built-in `gitattributes` for this:

in `.gitconfig` add:

```
[diff "my_diff"]
    command = Tools/csv_diff
    binary = true # Not sure this is required.
```

and in `.gitattributes` (either global or per repository, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28026767/where-should-i-place-my-global-gitattributes-file)) add:

```
*.csv diff=my_diff
```

---

[*] The command for the external diff tool will be called by git with the 7 parameters detailed under **GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF** in the manual [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git/2.18.0#Documentation/git.txt-codeGITEXTERNALDIFFcode).

Comment: Well, your comment actually threw me off-balance now :-). Git makes some distinction between a "diff driver" (which is defined under `diff` section in `.gitconfig`) and a "diff tool" (defined under `difftool` section), and I remember reading that a driver has to be text-based, but I don't see it anywhere in the manual now. So please try it out, it may work! if it does, post a comment and I'll update the answer. Another thing I don't know how I missed before is the option to add `binary = true` to the driver definition (right under `command = Tools/csv_diff`). Maybe this is the change needed.

Comment: Tested it and it works (Have written a programm what just displays the cli arguments and with .jpg as binary files) but `binary = true` was not necessary for me. But I'm still wondring why I can't alter how the cli arguments are provided like for `merge.<driver>.driver` (see [docu](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_defining_a_custom_merge_driver))

Comment: @Ackdari Cool! One thing I'm wondering about is what git does when it *needs* to show textual diffs and a GUI tool is defined (e.g. when you do git log -p for a few commits back)...

Comment: in my setup git just shows `Binary files /dev/null and b/bild.jpg differ`

Comment: Ok, that's what git usually shows for binary files, so I'm guessing it's detected as binary somewhere along the way.

Comment: Thanks!  I just needed one additional change to set my default atrributes file: `git config --global core.attributesfile /home/alex/.gitattributes`.  NB if you only want it in one repo then you need to write to `.git/info/attributes` (at least on Linux git).